# What is the meaning of symbol "vector deleting destructor" in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, destructor

This symbol seems to be a compiler generated destructor.  What is the difference between this one, 'compiler generated destructor' and 'scalar deleting destructor'? Are there any other types of compiler generated ctor/dtor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Functions named `'scalar deleting destructor'` and `'vector deleting destructor'` are helper functions created by VC compiler when generating code for `delete` statement. Don't confuse them with the class destructor which also may be generated by the compiler.
The former can be expressed in pseudocode as

```
void scalar_deleting_destructor(A* pa)
{
pa->~A();
A::operator delete(pa);
}
```

and the latter as

```
void vector_deleting_destructor(A* pa, size_t count)
{
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
pa[i].~A();
A::operator delete[](pa);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. I am a little confused about the inner delete operator here. This scalar deleting destructor is compiler generated and it is called by `delete a`, is this right? Seems the inner call to delete causes recursion?

Comment: @Thomson Let me try to make it more clear. `delete a` is a *delete statement*, i.e. a language construct, which is not to be confused with `A::operator delete` which is a *delete operator*, a function which actually deallocates the memory. I don't have the C++ standard at hand right now, I could provide references a bit later.

Answer (score -1):

I am using visual studio MSVC 2019  and C++20 also QT6
[image]

I have here in Windows with MSVC
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl QSslSocket::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EQSslSocket@@UEAAPEAXI@Z).